# How to place an image beneath a semi-transparent layer?

Tags: html, css, image, opacity, transparent

I know this has been asked before but I can't find a solution that works!

My site contains a green background with a form in the center of it. You can view the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ckedw6/1/) I simply want the image found [here](http://40.media.tumblr.com/9ba0ef66d65ee159bd1d8623964ffc8f/tumblr_njqrueR0gx1tkairwo1_1280.jpg) to be placed beneath the green layer you see. The image shouldn't be stretched - just simply fill the green layer with like 50% opacity.

The code that produces the green layer currently is:

```
#mainarea {

 height:900px;
  background: #2ecc71 no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
#mainarea::before {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  /* IE Fallback */
  background: white;
    width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some editing : check this http://jsfiddle.net/h6ckedw6/2/

added a new div for image

```
.bg{
    background:url(http://40.media.tumblr.com/9ba0ef66d65ee159bd1d8623964ffc8f/tumblr_njqrueR0gx1tkairwo1_1280.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    background-size:cover;
    width:100%;
 height:900px;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Worked with little hassle. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can get that effect by setting its background

checkout below link
http://jsfiddle.net/h6ckedw6/5/`background-color:rgba(2,236,199,0.5);`

Comment: That works, except I need it applied to the .mainarea class NOT the entire body. Can you help me modify it so it's only applied to the mainarea class (css code included in question). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a sampler solution , you can applay the color you want on the image using photoshop or any other image editor and play with the opacity then use `background-image` like so :

```
#mainarea {

 height:900px;
  background: #2ecc71 no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-image: url(http://s2.postimg.org/cp3x1a0w9/tumblr_njqrue_R0gx1tkairwo1_1280.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: "Roboto";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

}
```

**[link](http://s2.postimg.org/cp3x1a0w9/tumblr_njqrue_R0gx1tkairwo1_1280.jpg)** to the modified image

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h6ckedw6/3/)**

Comment: That's not simpler, because if I easily want to change the image I'll have to use Photoshop again. appreciate the advice though